# How to using CSS to set content of column to top not center in JSF, primefaces?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, panel

I have a panelGrid with some columns but content of one column always at center, how cant I take it to top. I have 2 columns and when content of them not same height, on columns will stay on center, so bad. Tks for help!

Comment: make sure the Question is very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the CSS `vertical-align` property to `top` on the generated HTML `<td>` element. Assuming that you want to apply this on the *entire* `<p:panelGrid>` throughout *all* pages, then this should do:

```
.ui-panelgrid td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

---

Or, if you want to apply it on a specific `<p:panelGrid>` only, then do:

```
<p:panelGrid ... styleClass="aligned-top">
```

with

```
.ui-panelgrid.aligned-top td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

---

Or, if you want to apply it on a specific `<p:panelGrid>` column only, e.g. the second column only, then do:

```
<p:panelGrid ... columns="3" columnClasses="none,aligned-top,none">
```

with

```
td.aligned-top {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/)